# Object variable not set in For loop

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to delete words from a Word document based on the style. For example, I would like to delete all words with style "Body_Text".

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(file_in)
'* file_in exists and is defined

Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set colWord = objDoc.Words

For Each objWords In colWord
    If objWords.Style = "Body_Text" Then
        objWords.Select
        objSelection.Delete
    End If
Next

objDoc.SaveAs(file_out)
'* file_out is defined

objWord.Quit
```

When I run this code, I get the error 800A005B "Object variable not set" at the statement

```
If objWords.Style = "Body_Text" Then
```

I expect to get the `file_out` with "Body_Text" style words deleted.

Comment: Your code ran fine(without errors) on my system. I deleted all the "Normal" style words without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but it seems like sometimes `objWords` is null.

You can easily add a test in your loop to avoid the error

```
For Each objWords in colWord
    If not objWords is Nothing Then '<< Check for nothing here to avoid error
        If objWords.Style = "Body_Text" Then
            objWords.Select
            objSelection.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```